# Update page breaks permalinks

Tags: permalinks, pages

I am having a strange side effect since going to 3.3.1. When updating pages (or creating new ones) all of my permalinks break - clicking view page on the updated page in question will result in  404 not found. This does not happen with posts.

I was concerned it might be an issue with my new schema for permalinks /%postname%/ but I swapped it to YEAR/POSTNAME and did not see any difference. I checked and found a few duplicates in the post-name fields, I changed or deleted any questionable repeats. Still no change.

Here is my htaccess -

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've also looked at [MonkeyMan's Rewrite analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) and nothing seems amiss there.

Any advice would be appreciated. Let me know if there is other information you need.

Comment: Does it happen when you disable all plugins and use the default theme?

Comment: I had tested it with all plugins off, and just as I was about to swap to 2011 I looked over all my custom taxonomies, which I coincidentally added around the 3.2.1 update. Lo and behold - I had foolishly added a 'year' taxonomy, changing that to 'show-year' seems to have licked it. Foolish mistake, thanks for the interest toscho.

Comment: One of the reasons why you should create custom taxonomies and post types in plugins only. :) Can this question be closed?

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and mark your question as _answered_. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tested it with all plugins off, and just as I was about to swap to 2011 I looked over all my custom taxonomies, which I coincidentally added around the 3.2.1 update. Lo and behold - I had foolishly added a 'year' taxonomy, changing that to 'show-year' seems to have licked it. Foolish mistake, thanks for the interest toscho. –